# Unexpected file "[" in /bin on macos

Tags: macos

I have an unexpected file named `[` -- a left bracket -- in my /bin file on my Mac Powerbook.   I'm running Catalina.  When I `cat` the file it looks like Apple certificate authority stuff.  Most of it is unreadable, but has text in it like

`Apple Certification Authority`

and

`PROGRAM:test  PROJECT:shell_cmds-207.40.1 ??????i@[]missing ]!unexpected operator%s: %s%sclosing paren expectedargument expected%s: bad number%s: out of range)`

Any idea what this could be?  Seems suspicious to me -- like some source code in it based on the error messages.  But don't want to just delete in case it is a file Apple needs.

Comment: What do you get if you do `file /bin/[`, `man [`, and `strings /bin/[`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The open square bracket, `[`, is a standard executable, equivalent to `test`, that provides syntactic sugar when writing shell scripts (i.e. it "looks nice")

```
fruit="banana"
if [ banana = "$fruit" ]    # "[" really is an executable
then
    echo "Yum, yum"
fi
```

Or

```
fruit="banana"
if test pear = "$fruit"
then
    echo "Yum, yum"
fi
```

These are directly equivalent.

In reality your shell probably implements both `[` and `test` directly, so that when you call them it's your shell actioning the command rather than running a separate process to do so. Again, no discernable difference to you, the user.

Comment: The only discernible difference between /usr/bin/test and /usr/bin/[ is that the latter requires a final argument of ], which is not a part of shell syntax. That syntactic sugar is catching. `if /usr/bin/[ 13 -lt 17 ]; then ...`

Comment: Thanks @roaima.  Not sure why the I got downvoted for the question -- couldn't find anything about this file with Google searches.  Appreciate taking time to help fill in the gaps for me.

Comment: @hoekma it's very difficult to search for punctuation. I've just amended my question to try and assist future searches